# How to sum the results without findall

Tags: prolog, clpfd

Is there an efficient and generic way of summing up results without generating an intermediate list:

```
main(A) :-
  B #< 4000000,
  B mod 2 #= 0,
  findall(B, fibonacci(_, B), Bs), 
  sum_list(Bs, A).
```

Note: this is Project Euler #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use predicate `[aggregate_all/3][1]` to do the aggregation without generating the intermediate list (runs in constant memory with SWI and I guess also with SICStus).

Instead of using `findall/3` + `sum_list/2` use `aggregate_all(sum(B), ..., Sum)`:

```
euler2(Sum):-
  B #< 4000000,
  B mod 2 #= 0,
  aggregate_all(sum(B), fibonacci(_, B), Sum).
```